# Assigning values in Angular scopes and objects contained therein

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just been reading this article on JavaScript inheritance and Angular Scopes:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

They refer to a bit of code like this:

> Suppose we then do this:
>
> ```
> childScope.aString = 'child string'
> ```

And then follow it up with:

> Suppose we then do this:
>
> ```
> childScope.anArray[1] = '22'
> childScope.anObject.property1 = 'child prop1'
> ```

Now the first one will get added to the child scope because it is not found in the parent.
However, the seconds ones are found in the parent and therefore will not get added to the child.

What I don't understand is that the `aString` appears in the parent scope as well, so how is it then that the 'prototype chain is not consulted' in this instance? It seems that all the examples should be able to refer to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve a value from an Angular scope, such as `childScope.aString`, if it's not contained in that scope directly then the parent scope would be consulted. However, the parent scope is not consulted when you assign directly to a property of the child scope, i.e. `childScope.x = y`.

In the case of `childScope.anArray[1] = '22'`, you *are not* assigning directly to a property of the child scope. You are assigning to a property/index of an object retrieved from the parent scope, through the child scope. You can break this line into two lines to clarify what is happening:

```
var array = childScope.anArray;
array[1] = '22';
```

The first line consults the parent scope, because you are *retrieving* the object `anArray` and it cannot be found in `childScope`. However, when you are assigning the value at index `[1]`, you are not assigning a property of the child scope, you are assigning a property to the object that was retrieved from the parent scope. Because the array object is visible in both scopes, the property you assigned to it will also be.

Comment: Having read your comment and looked at the article once again, the penny has finally dropped. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The prototype chain is not consulted when *setting* a property.

In the object examples, you're *getting* properties of the scope (`anObject` or `AnArray`), then setting properties of the returned objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding a property to an object.